# protractor not starting selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am encounteing following error when starting an end to end test using protractor.

```
manu@MANU:/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app$ ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor ./conf.js
[16:29:47] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:29:47] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[16:29:47] E/launcher - EINVAL: invalid argument, uv_interface_addresses
[16:29:47] E/launcher - Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, uv_interface_addresses
    at Error (native)
    at getLoInterface (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net/index.js:30:20)
    at getAddress (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net/index.js:46:14)
    at Object.exports.getLoopbackAddress (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net/index.js:85:10)
    at resolveCommandLineFlags.then.args (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:240:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:709:29)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.ts:90:25)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:225:39)
    at q.then.then (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:391:27)
    at _fulfilled (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[16:29:47] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
manu@MANU:/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app$
```

I could be because of issue in starting webdriver. I tried to run selenium but I got following error

```
manu@MANU:/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app$ ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start
[16:27:55] I/start - java -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.32 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.18.0 -jar /mnt/c/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/web/angular/dw-ng2-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -port 4444
[16:27:55] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: undefined
[16:27:55] W/start - Selenium Standalone server encountered an error: Error: spawn java ENOENT
```

I have tried cleaning and restarting using `clean` and `start` options with webdriver-manager but that hasn't solved the problem

Update---
I am running this on Windows machine through Bash for Windows. The issue with starting Selenium is Bash cannot find Java. I exported Path but because Java is installed in `Program Files`, I am unable to set the path in Bash as Bash is unable to process the space in `Program Files`. I could run the selenium server on CMD where JAVA path is set. The problem is still not resolved though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was I didn't install correctly the first time. I should have run `webdriver-manager update` from home directory. I cleaned up using `webdriver-manger clean` and re-run `webdriver-manger start` from project's home directory `project home> .\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager start`. Probably the installation sets some paths which get messed up if some other directory is used. I also started protractor from project's home directory `>node .\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor .\protractor.conf.js`

Comment: If you plan to launch with `directConnect`, you will need to make sure that the binaries exist in your project's local `node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium` directory. Protractor is looking for a file called `node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/update-config.json`. This file will appear when you do a successful `webdriver-manager update`. Protractor will find your ChromeDriver binary (based on the update-config.json` and should work from there. Also, you do not have to call `webdriver-manager start` unless you are going to use the standalone selenium server.  Hope that helps.